# Including glew using only source files?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, opengl, glew

For reasons outside of my comprehension, glew will simply not work when statically linked. Is there a way to simply just include the glew.h, glxew.h, wglew.h and glew.c source files into my project and use

```
#include "glew.h"
```

instead of

```
#include <glew.h>
```

whenever i try i get an explosion of warnings: like

```
warning C4273: '__WGLEW_NV_render_depth_texture' : inconsistent dll linkage
```

Comment: Add the glew path to your -I option if you are using gcc: `-I/path/to/glew`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have you seen the GLEW installation/building page?

http://glew.sourceforge.net/install.html

If you are building it statically (which it sounds like you are), you need to define the GLEW_STATIC macro before include glew.h (or else it won't compile).  The easiest way to do this is to add an option to your project; or if you are stubborn you could just do this:

```
 #define GLEW_STATIC
 #include "glew.h"
```

Answer (score 3):

From the GLEW [Installation page](http://glew.sourceforge.net/install.html):

"On Windows, you also need to define the GLEW_STATIC preprocessor token when building a static library or executable, and the GLEW_BUILD preprocessor token when building a dll. You also need to replace  and  with  in your code and set the appropriate include flag (-I) to tell the compiler where to look for it."